# Time series and Panel Data

Tags: r, time, time-series, panel-data

I have been trying to model a panel data to forecast the number of vehicles a junction can expect.Below is the format of data

---

```
junction_id       datetime                   vehicles                                             
1            11/11/2016 00:00:00             02                                               
1            11/11/2016 01:00:00             05                                            
1            11/11/2016 02:00:00             10                                        
2            11/11/2016 00:00:00             01                                         
2            11/11/2016 01:00:00             08                                            
2            11/11/2016 02:00:00             05
```

I have tried the plm package for the above data by giving the below formula

```
plm(vehicles~junction,index=c("junction","datetime"),model="within")
```

but I get empty model error
Can anyone help me please on this?Am i using the correct package because i understand that this is the case of panel data

Comment: Your model makes no sense. You are currently modeling the number of vehicles as a function of longitudinal change in _junction_id_. _junction_id_ is also your panel identifier and from the looks of it, you don't even have a time variable called _year_ in the sample.

Comment: You need to start from scratch.  Generally speaking, the `forecast`-package will probably accomplish what you are looking for, but you will have to coerce all your junction-specific data into time series objects and think about what kind of model (exponential smoothing, ARIMA) is suited for your data. You can start by looking at [this vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/forecast/vignettes/JSS2008.pdf) of the `forecast` package and perhaps Rob Hyndman's [online book](https://www.otexts.org/fpp). Good luck!

Comment: Sorry for the typo in the 'index' command of plm package.It should have been datetime instead of year.Have corrected it.So you are saying I would have to make 4 models corresponding to each junctions(I have 4 junctions in totality)?? Also I think its panel data cant we make a single model which will incorporate the junction and time series while forecasting future values??

Comment: I know currently the model that I have specefied dosent make any sense but to give a clear picture to everyone I wrote that statement here. Also i tried ARIMAX model as well but the fit was not that great and afterwards I realised that it is panel data so i was thinking if plm package could model my data.

Comment: Model choice depends on what you are trying to accomplish - how long do you want to forecast into the future? Are there any covariates you'd like to use to predict traffic? Do you expect there to be spatial dependencies between the different junctions? How much information do you have in terms of date?

Comment: At any rate, since you are only looking at four junctions in total, I don't think a panel model makes much sense. You can either forecast four different `auto.arima` or `ets` models for the junctions, or you automate the process by doing batch forecasting for all of the junctions. For that (and general convenience functions when using the `forecast` package), have a look at the `sweep` package. [This link](http://www.business-science.io/code-tools/2017/07/09/sweep-0-1-0.html) helped me tremendously when fitting my own batch forecasts.

Comment: Thanks tifu,I was initially thinking to fit four models and I suppose that should be simple and easy to manage,I would check on how to automate the batch processing and for your other question I would be looking to predict for 2 months on hourly basis.I currently have data for 2 years and data is available on hourly basis for each junction.Let me know if I can move ahead with 4 diffrent models for each junction.Thanks

Comment: Yeah, that would be easiest. Go for the `auto.arima` function as it is very likely you have strong seasonality patterns in your traffic data.

Comment: @tifu Can you please let me know if you know an answer for this question https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/370944/inference-using-panel-data-regression-model

Comment: I would suggest you read up on the differences between fixed and random effects regression, since you seem to be a beginner. Paul D. Allison's book 'Fixed Effects Regression Models' would be a good start, for example. In short, it is no surprise your coefficients change because FE and RE are estimated using different variation sources (FE only longitudinal variation, RE a weighted mix from both longitudinal and cross-sectional variation). There is absolutely no need to remove variables with p > 0.05 (that is never a good idea!)

Comment: Also, I'd suggest letting your research question dictate what method you use, rather than the Hausman test. If you are interested in longitudinal variation only (change within subjects), go with FE. If you want to explain the variation *both* within and across subjects, try a hybrid model. Using a pure RE approach is seldom a good idea, because your coefficients won't be interpretable in any meaningful way - but that is just my opinion.